# Is Ampere's law valid for changing currents?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Is Ampere's law only valid when the current is steady?

Comment: Amperes law is valid for de/dt = 0, the ampere-maxwell  equation is valid always.  Steady to mean divergenceless yes. You could also have e.g uniformly increasing current I believe aswell, and still satisfy amperes law

Comment: Does de/dt = 0 mean steady current or static electric field?

Comment: static electric field, however a steady current can produce a static electric field. a changing current can also produce a static electric field

Answer (score 1):

Ampere's law is not valid even in some cases where current is steady, e.g. when electric field flux through the imaginary loop changes in time, but current does not. This can happen inside a capacitor that is being charged using a device in the circuit that maintains constant charging current.

The only certainty is that if electric field is static, then Ampere's law holds. If electric field changes in time, Ampere's law may not hold.

Comment: @ Jan Lalinsky: When the electric field is static and the current changes, is Ampere's law valid?

Comment: Yes. This follows immediately from the Maxwell-Ampere law.

Comment: @ Jan Lalinsky: It looks correct but maybe there is another possibility: The changing current produces a changing magnetic field. This magnetic field, according to Faraday's law, produces an electric field. And if this field changes with time, the Ampere's law is not valid.

Comment: if your changing current produces a changing electric field, amperes law is not valid. Jans statement is consistent with your question

Comment: @AndreasValadakis yes. But changing current need not produce changing electric field. E.g. if we have infinite solenoid and current in it changes linearly in time, then induced electric field is constant in time, and does not invalidate the Ampere law.